# Post location on facebook with latitude and longitude coordinates only

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I am creating a native Windows Phone App, and I would like to have a functionality that enables making facebook wall posts with location displayed on the map(like when you tag some place).

It might seem a duplicate question but I haven't managed to find C# code for that.

So I need to post place, but I have only latitude and longitude, **no facebook placeId**

here is sample code that doesn't work:

```
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        parameters["message"] = txtMessage.Text;

        var place = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        place["location"] = new GeoCoordinate { Latitude = 60.1654712,
                                                     Longitude = 24.9220499 };
        parameters["place"]=place;
        fb.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try searching for places within a certain distance of your lat/long coordinates, and let the user chose one of the results.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching for details.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that option but is there a possibility to tag place exactly from coordinates? I know you can create new places in native facebook app, but I haven't found api for that

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be a way to do it via API, but here someone describes how it could be done using Open Graph objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017790/can-a-developer-add-places-to-facebook-checkin – maybe you can use that?