# Android Facebook Places using Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to android. I searched for the places using Graph Api as follows

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Hyderabad&type=place&access_token=.....
```

Here "Hyderabad" is my search place. It has given the successful result .The result containing id's for each place.  N0w My questions are

1)How can I add particular place to my favorites section?

2)How can I create new place?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1)How can I add particular place to my favorites section?

What do you mean by that?  Can you elaborate?

For your second question, [read this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018301/931354) and that will answer your question.